# dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++

here is  example how Pointers are used to store and manage the addresses of dynamically allocated blocks of memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct Item{
    int id;
    char* name;
    float cost;
    };
   struct Item*make_item(const char *name){
        struct Item *item;
        item=malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
        if (item==NULL)
             return NULL;
        memset(item,0,sizeof(struct Item));
        item->id=-1;
        item->name=NULL;
        item->cost=0.0;

         /* Save a copy of the name in the new Item */
        item->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
        if (item->name=NULL){
            free(item);
            return NULL;
        }

        strcpy(item->name,name);
         return item;

        }

int main(){



     return 0;
}
```

but here is mistakes

1

```
>------ Build started: Project: dynamic_memory, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  dynamic_memory.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dynamic_memory\dynamic_memory.cpp(11): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Item *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dynamic_memory\dynamic_memory.cpp(20): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

what is wrong?please help

Comment: This is very nearly correct C, but it's bad C++ (even with the compiler errors fixed with a cast).  I'd suggest picking one language for a program and using it properly.

Comment: I just don't get it. 202 questions. Still no idea how to format a post or how to write a proper question. Reputation continously growing.

Comment: Why is this marked as C++. This is obviously C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At row 11
`item=malloc(sizeof(struct Item));`
must become
`item=(Item *)malloc(sizeof(struct Item));`

At row 20
`item->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);`
must become
`item->name=(char *)malloc(strlen(name)+1);`

At row 21
`if (item->name=NULL){`
must become
`if (item->name==NULL){`.

Comment: The memset call is probably also superfluous.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is C++, you need to cast the return from malloc as C++ does not automatically convert a `void *` to a `T *`:

```
item=static_cast<Item *>(malloc(sizeof(struct Item)));
```

Or even better, stop using `malloc` and use `new` instead and you won't have to cast:

```
item = new Item;
item->name = new char[strlen(name + 1)];
```

That said, if you do use `new`, you need to free with `delete`:

```
delete[] item->name;
delete item;
```

Also, if you use `new`, by default the runtime will inform you about out of memory by throwing an exception.  While it's best to learn how to deal with exceptions as a temporary stop gap, you can have the nothrow version of `new` so that it will return 0 when out of memory:

```
item = new (std::nothrow) Item;
```

Comment: If this is C++, it shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place.  Instead, use `new` to get an array of bytes.

Comment: Also consider using a constructor rather than a function to create a new object.  This would be absolutely trivial with `std::string` and a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree with previous answers -- if this is going to be used in a C++ program, do it the C++ way.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Item{
    int id;
    string name;
    float cost;
    Item(char *pName) : id(-1), name(pName), cost(0) {}
    };
// Look ma, no "make_item"!
```

Then, where you would have used make_item:

```
    ...
    pItem = make_item("hoozit");
    ...
```

replace that code with:

```
    ...
    pItem = new Item("hoozit");
    ...
```

Comment: Only thing this is missing is the obligatory "There, I fixed it for ya" comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fix your compilation errors...

Change this:

```
item=malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
```

To:

```
item=(item*)malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
```

and this:

```
item->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
```

To:

```
item->name=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
```

Comment: `(item*)` must be `(Item*)`. :)